# Fibre Optic port moving to 1000Mb/s eventhough it is not in the supported link mode

Tags: linux-networking, drivers, linux-kernel, fiber, network-speed

In my Fibre Optic device (Linux 2.6.27, LXT971A PHY Transceiver), connection to the port is lost intermittently. While debugging with ETHtool, the following observation was observed:

`Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: external
Auto-negotiation: off
Link detected: yes`

The Switch used (ruggedcom) supports only **100Mb/s FULL DUPLEX** . Why is the speed moved to **1000Mb/s** and the link detected is **"yes"** ? After this stage is reached the port will not try any other speed and stays in 1000Mb/s until device restart. Please note that the issue is observed only with a FO cable of length 30m or more and works fine with FO cable of length 2m.

Any comments or insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The **BMCR and BMSR**  are in the following Modes: BMCR = 2100 (100Mbps,full duplex) BMSR = 780D

Comment: You need to add hardware details. The Intel LXT971A is a 10BASE-T/100BASE-TX copper transceiver. Are you using fiber or twisted pair??